# ??? Input argument "x" is undefined

Tags: matlab

I enter:

```
EDU>> %using the temporary variable levels
EDU>> levels=range/quantise_range;
levels=round(levels);
quantisation_bits=log2(levels)
```

NB. There is no x variable anywhere

My error is:

```
??? Input argument "x" is undefined.

Error in ==> range at 18
    y = max(x) - min(x);

EDU>> %combining above process into one statement
quantisation_bits=log2(round(range/quantise_range));
??? Input argument "x" is undefined.

Error in ==> range at 18
    y = max(x) - min(x);
```

Would someone care to explain thie issue? I am beginner into programming and I really don't understand how to read the error hint.

Thanks.

Additionally, in what may be due to whatever the same principle misunderstanding on my part is, I am finding trouble here with this code, with error also included:

%Trying to create my own function, I’m pressing shift+enter at the end of lines for neatness:

```
EDU>> function what_am_i()
disp 'I am a function'
??? function what_am_i()
    |
Error: Function definitions are not
permitted in this context.

EDU>> 
function what_am_i()
disp' I am a function'
??? function what_am_i()    
    |
Error: Function definitions are not
permitted in this context.

EDU>> end
??? end
    |
Error: Illegal use of reserved keyword
"end".
```

Answer (score 2):

You may be confusing the "Command Window" with the "Editor".
In the "Command Window" you can enter some lines of code, but can't create functions. It acts more like a calculator.

If you create and save files, then you open them in the "Editor" and that's when Matlab begins behaving more like a programming language. It saves `.m` files that can have functions or algorithms written in them.

Matlab has lots of help available. I recommend visiting their website and searching around a bit.  (or just google "intro to matlab")

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @user1860611's answer regarding function definitions in the command window, the other problem you have has to do with [range](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/range.html), which is a built-in function.  It appears you are trying to use `range` it as a variable name, but didn't actually initialize it to a value, so it is still a function.

In the line here:

```
levels=range/quantise_range;
```

you are essentially calling the `range` function, but without passing it an argument.

```
Error in ==> range at 18
y = max(x) - min(x);
```

The error message is telling you that a function called `range` has generated an error.  It doesn't matter that you don't have a variable named `x`, because the function has one internally.